# Toggle Picking Ticket Printed ('T' or 'F')

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In Suitescript, is there a way to toggle the Printed Picking Ticket flag between true/false?

Scenario is required if a Picking Ticket has been printed, then the client decides to Ship Complete, currently the flag does not reset, therefore someone has to remember to reprint the picking ticket once the order is completed.

I cannot find the appropriate field in the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Printed Picking Ticket" `printedpickingticket` is only a Search Filter, not an actual field on the record, so it doesn't seem there would be a way to toggle it. There is the `tobeprinted` field, but I'm not sure that would accomplish what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tobeprinted` only sets the flag whether to print the sales order confirmation or not.

Guess I'll have to put it to netsuite to see if it's scriptable, or maybe delve into SuiteScript 2.0 API